# Swift - when or how to implement animations on view start?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to implement a simple game. In this game, once the view is loaded I want periodic animations to happen.

The problem is that I try to animate my buttons with, for instance, `button.frame.origin.x += 50`, but instead of moving it from the origin to 50px right, it appears at button.frame.origin.x - 50 and goes to its (initial) position.
Funnily enough, at one point I show an `AlertDialog` to the user, and after it is shown the animation starts to happen as I expected.

My problem is the same of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111770/make-a-simple-fade-in-animation-in-swift), but the accepted answer just didn't solve it for me.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
Digging into the code and testing a lot I found out the method where I show the AlertDialog also happens to invalidate my timer. I have two timers: one to update the UI time (a TextField), and the other to perform the animation. Both are scheduling a task. From what [I read here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html), it is not possible to have two timers like that.

> A timer object can be registered in only one run loop at a time,
>   although it can be added to multiple run loop modes within that run
>   loop.

Hence, the obvious solution would be to merge the two selectors (functions) into one, so the timer would work for both tasks. However, if I try to update the UI AND perform animations, the animations don't work as expected anymore. I'm just lost on this problem and can't make both things work.

These are my important pieces of code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    ...

    resetOrCreateGame()
}

func resetOrCreateGame() {
    // Do stuff to initialize values
    timerToRotate = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "rotateBlocks", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func rotateBlocks() {
    // Calculate positions to rotate
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        // Try to update a timer in the UI
        //self.timeLeft.text = String(self.seconds)

        for i in 0 ... 8 {
            println("\(i) before \(self.buttons[i].frame.origin.x) \(self.buttons[i].frame.origin.y)")
            self.buttons[i].frame.origin.x = self.positions[self.indicesToRotate[i]].x
            self.buttons[i].frame.origin.y = self.positions[self.indicesToRotate[i]].y

            println("\(i) after \(self.buttons[i].frame.origin.x) \(self.buttons[i].frame.origin.y)")
        }
        }, completion: { _ in
                println("completed")
            })
```

If I leave the line `self.timeLeft.text = String(self.seconds)` commented, the animations work fine. No matter how I try to update the timeLeft, if I do so it screws my animations. I tried to update it in a separate thread, dispatch it to the main thread, or even update it inside the animations closure: it just doesn't work.

Comment: You can use many timers in your app. That is fine. The description that you show talks about one timer and how it can be added to only one run loop at a time.

Comment: The problem seems to be the thread updating the UI, or something like that. Even using only one timer it still doesn't work. Please see the code I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution!
The problem for some reason was Auto Layout. After disabling it everything worked as expected.

Hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SKAction`s to animate.

Set up an `SKAction`, then on the `SpriteKit node` you want to animate (replace "`node`" with the name of the node), and call it `action`.

Then, call the simple method:

`[node runAction:action];`

For example, if you want to set up an `SKAction` to move a node titled `button` 50 pixels to the right over a timespan of 3 seconds...

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveByX:50.0 y:0.0 duration:3.0];
[button runAction:action];
```

Heck, if I don't run an action more than once, I'd simply do this:

```
[button runAction:[SKAction moveByX:50.0 y:0.0 duration:3.0]];
```

And finally, you can use the `runAction:completion:` method to not only run your `SKAction`, but to call an Objective-C `block` after it's finished, like in this coding example:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveByX:50.0 y:0.0 duration:3.0];
[button runAction:action completion:^{
     // some code here that runs after an animation completes
}];
```

And, to non-complicate your code if you want to run a *sequence* of actions on a node (move a button 50 pixels to the right called `button` over 3 seconds, then fade it out over 1 second), you can program a sequence of actions into one action, like so:

```
SKAction *firstAction = [SKAction moveByX:50.0 y:0.0 duration:3.0];
SKAction *secondAction = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:1.0];
SKAction *theSequence = [SKAction sequence:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstAction, secondAction, nil];
[button runAction:theSequence]
```

You CAN run another action in the `completion` block, but the method of using a `sequence` cleans up code.

Comment: Wait a minute... my answer's in Objective-C. You would use the Swift equivalent of that.

Comment: Well, thanks for your examples. However I want to perform a very simple animation, and I suppose there is a pretty simple solution to what I'm already doing.

Comment: I'd just use an `SKAction` for SpriteKit animations and let that take care of it. Try reading the documentation for it!